# Why does when I import pynput and use it it deletes my python file?

Tags: python, windows, delete-file, pynput, keylogger

something weird is happening.
In short explanation - my .py file gets deleted automatically when I use `pynput` lib
Detailed explanation -
I create a file called `keylog.py`
I have installed ->`pip install pynput`, 
when I run the code:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=("keylog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")
 
def onPress(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
```

Everything is ok.

But when I add:

```
# from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
 
logging.basicConfig(filename=("keylog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")
 
def onPress(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
 
# with Listener(on_press=onPress) as listener:
#    listener.join()
```

Even if the pynput import is commented out the `keylog.py` file gets deleted automatically.
I have no idea why this happen, I tried to delete PyCharm and re-install, I tried working in VScode, same thing happening.
I didn't configure something special.
I would like some help and explanation why this happen, Thanks.

Comment: I can't really reproduce the error, tried your second code snippet (without the comments of course) and it works flawlessly for me.

Comment: This seems very unlikely. Have you reproduced the error using just the code you have shared here? Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Does your code accidentally specify the logging filename as `keylog.py` instead of `keylog.txt`?

Comment: hey @Chris, I'm not sure how you guide helps me. I cant debug because the file Delete it self even before I Ctrl+S.
even if I saved it, as soon as I try to run the file, I get error that file is missing and then the file disappears.

Comment: Hey @evergreen, nope. I tried changing the name of the file to hello.py and still deletes..

Comment: I just encountered this problem. Windows 10's security basically put all my folder in "read-only" mode because it thinks it detected a keylogger threat... That's why the files disappear or can't be saved.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue if anyone in the future will have the same problem.
when I opened a project for some reason it didn't ask me if I want to trust this project.
therefore, the windows defender sees `pynput` as maybe malicious so it blocked these files, until I made them trusted.

Comment: Quick question how have you done that? I am encountering the same problem and the only options in Windows Defender are "remove" and "quarantine"... I will search a little more of course

Comment: Well I just randomly deleted a line in the thread and it apparently solved that issue.?

Answer (score 0):

Basically pynput is used to record keystrokes which is termed as Malicious in Windows Security. Try Disabling it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).